# Image doesn't display with MUI React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, image, material-ui

I try to display my pictures with itemDate.js file :

```
const itemData = [
    {
      img: "../assets/photos/photoportrait.jpeg",
      title: 'Breakfast',
    },
```

and calling with my Portfolio component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import ImageList from '@mui/material/ImageList';
import ImageListItem from '@mui/material/ImageListItem';
import itemData from './itemData';


function Portfolio() {

return(
<ImageList sx={{ width: 500, height: 450 }} cols={3} rowHeight={164}>
  {itemData.map((item) => (
    <ImageListItem key={item.img}>
      <img
        src={item.img}
        srcSet={item.img}
        alt={item.title}
        loading="lazy"
      />
    </ImageListItem>
  ))}
</ImageList>
```

there is no error message, the path is correct but nothing appear on my page. It's working with link but doesn't works with local path. any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this similar issue and come to find out you have to return every item from your map. So just add a `return` statement in your map function like so:

```
import * as React from "react";
import ImageList from "@mui/material/ImageList";
import ImageListItem from "@mui/material/ImageListItem";

const itemData = [
  {
    img: "../assets/photos/photoportrait.jpeg",
    title: "Breakfast"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ImageList sx={{ width: 500, height: 450 }} cols={3} rowHeight={164}>
      {itemData.map((item) => (
         return (
        <ImageListItem key={item.img}>
          <img
            src={item.img}
            srcSet={item.img}
            alt={item.title}
            loading="lazy"
          />
        </ImageListItem>
      )))}
    </ImageList>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it works for me too. mui seems to have a lot of issues IMO

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting any issue with your code. I just copied your code and prepare a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/imageexample-icfoi?file=/src/App.js:0-628) and run it. it works fine.

Here is the complete code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import ImageList from "@mui/material/ImageList";
import ImageListItem from "@mui/material/ImageListItem";

const itemData = [
  {
    img: "../assets/photos/photoportrait.jpeg",
    title: "Breakfast"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ImageList sx={{ width: 500, height: 450 }} cols={3} rowHeight={164}>
      {itemData.map((item) => (
        <ImageListItem key={item.img}>
          <img
            src={item.img}
            srcSet={item.img}
            alt={item.title}
            loading="lazy"
          />
        </ImageListItem>
      ))}
    </ImageList>
  );
}
```